# virtualbis Page transitions in React with Highway

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gsap

I am just testing out the page transitions and am running into errors, even when I use the example in https://highway.js.org/examples/transitions.html

It is showing "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null"

Here is a link to my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-northcutt-bilpx

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that Highway doesn't work with React at the moment, as mentioned in these issues:

https://github.com/Dogstudio/highway/issues/50

https://github.com/Dogstudio/highway/issues/64

The alternative would be to use React Transition Group for that.

Comment: Thank you @Rodrigo. I just notice your gsap post. Researching now. Any good tutorials you could point me towards?